# Upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) with nginx + Tomcat + Amazon EC2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, tomcat

On an Amazon EC2 instance, we have nginx and Tomcat running. Nginx is proxying all requests to Tomcat on port 8080 running on the same instance.

This worked fine for a day, but then started seeing a lot of  `upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out)` errors in the nginx logs and the site was inaccessible. Now Tomcat is accessible all right at port 8080. So the problem seems to be somewhere between nginx and Tomcat.

This is what `nginx.conf` looks like,

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  domainname.com;
        rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.domainname.com/$1 permanent;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  www.domainname.com;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_read_timeout 120;
            proxy_connect_timeout 120;
        }

    }
}
```

Any insights would be helpful.

**Update:**
After restarting the instance, the site has started to work. I have absolutely no idea what the problem was, but I'll monitor it for a while for such problems.

Comment: Did you actually run into the problem again and got it fixed for real? I'm asking since I started to run into the situation you described a couple of times during the last months: nginx <-> upstream connection timeout although the upstream runs fine and fast when queried directly. A reload of the nginx workers then makes the problem disappear...

Comment: as far as i can remember, i didn't run into this problem after. A few months later, I moved out of the project and have no idea since. You may want to try Fleshgrinder's solution below and monitor it for a while. As it stands, I really don't know what the real problem was nor the real solution :) Best wishes.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following for redirecting:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domainname.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Add the following to your configuration:

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
```

And evaluate, or post the result here.

Comment: the site started working after a restart, without any config changes. is there a reason for preferring a 'return' instead of a 'rewrite' ?

Comment: WAY FASTER! There is no regular expression to parse and compile each time a request comes in.